# How do I get python to read only every other line from a file that contains a poem

Tags: file, loops, lines

I know the code for reading every line is

```
f=open ('poem.txt','r')
for line in f: 
    print line
```

how do you have python read only even-numbered lines from the original file. Assuming 1-based numbering of lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways, here a simple one

```
with open('poem.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        count+=1
        if count % 2 == 0: #this is the remainder operator
            print(line)
```

This also might be a little nicer, saving the lines for declaring and incrementing the count:

```
with open('poem.txt', 'r') as f:
    for count, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if count % 2 == 0:
            print(line)
```

Comment: This is definitely correct, although the pythonic way to open the file would be with a context manager, such that `with open('poem.txt', 'r') as f:` would be what you want (that way the file is closed properly if you crash, etc.

Comment: Yeah, your right, should show best practice, have amended.

Comment: Of course in the land of best practice one should also use `enumerate`:  `for count,line in enumerate(f, start=1): if count % 2 == 0...`  and thus avoid creating or incrementing the counter yourself.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

From [Nick Bastin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551945/how-do-i-get-python-to-read-only-every-other-line-from-a-file-that-contains-a-po#comment49176633_30551984):

```
with open('poem.txt', 'r') as f:
    for count, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if count % 2 == 0:
            print line
```

Comment: How can I read tab delimited text from every other line and convert it to float?

Comment: @CV_passionate Try `float(n) for n in line.split("\t")`