# How can i adjust my code to read every other line?

Tags: python, list

```
with open(data_path) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]
```

The following code will read every single line and insert it into a list.
But the code i want should read the first line and skip the second then read the third or simply adjust content to "remove" values with `odd` indices number.

Comment: Is it an upgrade? If you use that method you're essentially iterating over the lines of the file **twice**. Wouldn't it be better to read the lines you want and store them all in just one pass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get python to read only every other line from a file that contains a poem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30551945/how-do-i-get-python-to-read-only-every-other-line-from-a-file-that-contains-a-po)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set step equals to 2 in your list comprehension

```
content = [x.strip() for x in content[::2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you stated your problem:

> should read the first line and skip the second then read the third

You can do all things in one line :

> One line solution:

```
print([item.strip() for index,item in enumerate(open('file.txt','r')) if index % 2 == 0])
```

> above list comprehension is same as:

```
final_list=[]
for index,item in enumerate(open('file.txt','r')):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        final_list.append(item.strip())
```

Comment: @vishes_shell yea i know , but python take care of that generally.Some Pythons will close files automatically when they are no longer referenced, while others will not and it's up to the O/S to close files when the Python interpreter exits.

Comment: Sure it does, but usually we might use same file over and over, and without closing it, or without using context manager we won't be able to do anything.

Comment: @vishes_shell yea , but i just shown one line solution, but i agree with you :)